# TypeError when instantiaing SpotifyWebApi object

Tags: javascript, api, typeerror, undefined, spotify

im trying to write a bot to do some playlist handling in spotify. I'm using the spotify-web-api-node package : https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node

I installed the package and whenever I try to create an object with the following code:

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const spotifyApp = SpotifyWebApi();
```

I keep getting this error:

```
this._credentials = credentials || {};
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_credentials')
```

this is the contructor signature in the src file:

```
 constructor(credentials?: Credentials);
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an `access-token` for access API call.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node),

If you've got an access token and want to use it for all calls, simply use the API object's set method. Handling credentials is described in detail in the Authorization section.

```
spotifyApi.setAccessToken('<your_access_token>');
```

Demo code: get access token then get Elvis' albums

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const axios = require('axios')

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            data = '',
            config = {
                params: {
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: '<your client id>',
                    password: '<your client secret>'
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(response.data.access_token);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getToken()
    .then(token => {
        const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token);
        // Passing a callback - get Elvis' albums in range [0...1]
        spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('43ZHCT0cAZBISjO8DG9PnE', { limit: 2, offset: 0 }).then(
            (data) => {
                console.log('Artist albums', data.body);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            }
        );
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Yes i know that I have to get an access token in order to use the API, but the documention states that I need to set the access token after I instantiate the spotify object, and this is the line where i get the error. for exmaple:

const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const spotifyApp = SpotifyWebApi();
spotifyApp.setAccessToken('access_token');

gives me an error in the second line.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think your token is not valid. Did you chance to run my demo code?
It is verified, it should be works if use proper client id/secret.
Also confirmed the library version is correct.
"spotify-web-api-node" is "5.0.2".

Comment: ok i will try running it again, thank you